# Creating customized php files in theme folder

Tags: php, functions, hooks, urls

I am developing a e-commerce theme that requires an order page. I created a php file inside my theme folder named order-page.php and hope to access this page from the wordpress root url (example.com/order-page)

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'template_redirect');
function template_redirect(){
    $basename = basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    echo $basename;
    if($basename=='order-page'){
        loadCustomTemplate(TEMPLATEPATH."/$basename.php");
    }
}

function loadCustomTemplate($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    if(!file_exists($template)){
        return;
    }
    $wp_query->is_page = true;
    $wp_query->is_single = false;
    $wp_query->is_home = false;
    $wp_query->comments = false;
    // if we have a 404 status
    if ($wp_query->is_404) {
    // set status of 404 to false
        unset($wp_query->query["error"]);
        $wp_query->query_vars["error"]="";
        $wp_query->is_404=false;
    }
    // change the header to 200 OK
    //header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    //load our template
    include($template);
    exit;
}
```

**Problem#1**: with the function listed above, I can only use example.com/?order-page to get what I want. If I use example.com/order-page, I will get `url not found` error.

**Problem#2**: when I have multiple parameters, this function doesn't work anymore. For example, if I have:

```
example.com/?order-page&product_id=001&type=digital
```

`$basename`will return `order-page&product_id=001&type=digital`

Using `$query_array=explode('&',$basename)` and get `$query_array[0]` is one possible solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you could add a query var and rewrite rule, but you're better off creating a page rather than "faking" one this way. I can immediately think of 10 different issues with this- menus, widgets, sitemap, caching, plugin integration, etc.. store the ID of the order page in an option so users can choose the page, and/or auto-insert the new page.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem#1:

You can create a customized php file for your page using a **Page Template**

> #### [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/)
>
> WordPress looks for template files in the following order:
>
> 1. Page Template — If the page has a custom template assigned, WordPress looks for that file and, if found, uses it.
> 2. page-{slug}.php — If no custom template has been assigned, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template that contains the
>    page’s slug.
> 3. page-{id}.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s slug is not found, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template
>    named with the page’s ID.
> 4. page.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s ID is not found, WordPress looks for and uses the theme’s default page
>    template.
> 5. index.php — If no specific page templates are assigned or found, WordPress defaults back to using the theme’s index file to render
>    pages.

In your scenario, your page template file would be **page-order-page.php**, wordpress would then load that file for when someone accesses (example.com/order-page).

### Problem#2:

For problem 2, you would need to register query variables using the [**`query_vars`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) filter.

```
function wpse169050_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'product_id';
    $vars[] = 'type';
    return $vars;
} 
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse169050_register_query_vars' );
```

Your order url with the variables would then be

```
example.com/order-page/?product_id=001&type=digital
```

You can then get the value for both variables using [**`get_query_var`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) in your template file:

```
$product_id = get_query_var('product_id');
$type       = get_query_var('type');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the WordPress hierarchy page in the documentation. Here it's the relevant part:

```
page-{slug}.php
```

If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use:

```
page-recent-news.php
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy